# Obtaining predicted (i.e. expected) values from the orm function (Ordinal Regression Model) from rms package in R

Tags: r, regression, predict

I've run a simple model using orm (i.e. reg <- orm(formula = y ~ x)) and I'm having trouble understanding how to get predicted values for Y. I've never worked with models that use multiple intercepts. I want to know for each and every value of Y in my dataset what the predicted value from the model would be. I tried predict(reg, type="mean") and this produced values that are close to the predicted values from an OLS regression, but I'm not sure if this is what I want. I really just want something analogous to OLS where you can obtain the E(Y) given a set of predictors. If possible, please provide code I can run to do this with a very short explanation.

Comment: `orm` belongs to some package? Does not it have `predict` implemented, ie, `predict(reg)`?

Comment: Yes orm belongs to the rms package. I can get predicted values using predict(reg, type = "mean") and I'm looking for some explanation of how the model output (i.e. intercepts and parameters) is converted to a predicted value. The documentation for predict.orm has the following: "For an ordinal response variable, type="mean" computes the estimated mean Y by summing values of Y multiplied by the estimated Prob(Y=j)."

Comment: If you type `rms:::predict.orm` you will discover this function invokes `predict.lrm` whose code you can examine typing `rms:::predict.lrm`. You always can discover these _hidden functions_ code  as explained [here](https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/finding-the-code-for-hidden-function-in-r/comment-page-1/).